# How to secure a product URL in config.xml?

Tags: product, secure

Lets say, I have a product, its URL is: http://www.whatever.com/my-url-key. How can I secure it? I tried:

```
<secure_url>
    <product>/my-url-key</product>
</secure_url>
```

This did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: are you want for a product ya all products???

Comment: For one product with url key "my-url-key", NOT for all products.

Comment: ok,lets see....

Answer (score 3):

1. Add "is_secure" attribute to product attributes:

   - Attribute Code: is_secure
   - Scope: global
   - Used In Product Listing: yes
   - Visible on Product View: yes
2. Join this attribute to any attribute set.
3. Open any product and set `is_secure` attribute to "yes" .
4. Use this code while generating the link to the product:

```
    <a  href="<?php echo $_product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($_product, array('_secure'=>(bool)$_product->getIsSecure())) ?>">
```

Or you can change `$_product->getProductUrl()` to  `$_product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($_product, array('_secure'=>(bool)$_product->getIsSecure()))` anywhere like catalaog/product/list.phtml

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've modified mageUzs answer a bit so I do not need to work with an extra attribute:

```
$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, array('_secure'=>(bool)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()))
```

This works perfectly for me. Thanks.